# coordinate function mouse down in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

i will make my hammer(movie clip) following cursor and every time I click the mouse / mouse down, the hammer will come down exposed cursor and return to original position. But i just can make the hammer(movie clip) following cursor. How can I do?

```
hammer.startDrag(true);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhSFW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I received your file here is the new code :

```
Mouse.hide();   //Hide the mouse cursor

//The stage listen the mouse movement
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, functionA);
function functionA(evt:MouseEvent){
    //On mouse movement, the hammer position will change
    hammer.x = mouseX; //If you want you can add an offset (ex : stage.mouseX - 5; )
    hammer.y = mouseY;
    //That's exactly the same as hammer.startDrag(true); but with something more cool, it's you can add an offset for X/Y axes.
}

//The stage is listening on mouse button down
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, functionName2);
function functionName2(evt:MouseEvent){
 //On mouse button down, we enter the movieclip "hammer" and on the timeline we go to and play (gotoAndPlay :D) the label "HammerDown"
 //Now if you double click on the hammer on the stage, you will enter the movieclip and you will find a layer call "Labels"
 //I called it like that, the name is not important. In Flash you can add a name to a key frame or a group of keys. Maybe you don't see
 //any advantage for now but trust me, that's much more upgradable like that. So in my first answer on Stackoverflow I wrote to you
 //to type : gotoAndPlay( 1 ), the number was the key's number, but this time I've change it to "HammerDown" wich is the name of my label
 //on the layer labels inside hammer's movieclip.
 //So at the end what happen is : When the stage receive a mouse down event, the script enter "hammer" movieclip and gotoAndPlay the animation
 //start from the first key of "HammerDown" label. That's what the line below means.
 hammer.gotoAndPlay( "HammerDown" ); //2 is the number of the key wich contains the hammer with down position

 //To give a label's name to a key or a group of key, just click on a keyframe, go to Propriety -> Label -> Name and that's it!

}

//On mouse button up
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, functionName3);
function functionName3(evt:MouseEvent){
    //On mouse up the script enter hammer's movieclip and gotoAndPlay the animation inside "hammer" movieclip, wich start from "HammerUp".
    //The trick is that the animation will be stop because at the same time, the script read the stop(); and so the animation is stop inside "Hammer".
   hammer.gotoAndPlay("HammerUp"); //1 is the number of the key wich contains the hammer with up position
}
```

And here is your file with my editing :
[File](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/7ba8df99ae8e3794da10fcb736eb72e220151229223522/270af5)

Comment: wow... thank you so much for your answer @Xue Fang, this is helpful for me :)

Comment: You are welcome ;) if there is something too complex in the file after my editing, just ask.

Comment: hy @Xue Fang , can you help me ? :D

Comment: Yes, what's happening?

Comment: I would like to make a highscore by using 4 if-else is lost in level 1, 2, 3 and wins in level 3. The use amfphp mysql, so from the beginning I did not understand to make it. What should I do?

Comment: You should create a complete new question to let everyone can help you. I don't know amfphp but do you really need a database for a highscore? If the project stay simple you could just use a XML as a saving file, it also works offline this way.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use a movieclip with the hammer. Inside this movieclip you have your timeline, on the first keyn of the timeline you stick the hammer with the "up" position and on this same key you type the following code

```
stop();
```

And then on the next key you create a new frame with the hammer down, you also add :

```
stop();
```

That will stop the frame reader on the first key and what we are going to do is to instance the movieclip on the stage and make it follow the mouse.

```
//Instance the hammer
var hammer:Hammer = new Hammer(); //Hammer is the name of you class on the movieclip in your flash library

stage.addChild(hammer); //instance on the stage

//Add an event listener on the stage wich is trigger when the mouse move
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, functionName);
    function functionName2(evt:MouseEvent){
       hammer.x = stage.mouseX; //If you want you can add an offset (ex : stage.mouseX - 5; )
       hammer.y = stage.mouseY; 
    }
```

Now the hammer should be moving and following the mouse :

```
//On mouse button down
hammer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, functionName2);
function functionName2(evt:MouseEvent){
   evt.target.goToAndStop(2); //2 is the number of the key wich contains the hammer with down position
}

//On mouse button up
hammer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, functionName3);
function functionName3(evt:MouseEvent){
   evt.target.goToAndStop(1); //1 is the number of the key wich contains the hammer with up position
}
```

The advantage of this technic is that if you feel friendly with Flash animation, you can create a small animation between keys with "goToAndPlay(x)", that's not only "up/down", you can add some fun.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your answer @Geoffrey . I try this code and i following this step one by one but error, "type was not found or was not a compile-time constans:Hammer, Call to a possibly undefined method Hammer". in var hammer:Hammer = new Hammer(); .

Comment: Oh this is because you probably didn't declare your hammer movieclip as a class inside the library. To correct it you have 2 solutions : 1- you go in your flash library, go in proprieties of your movieclip and you should find an input call export for action script, check it and then you have another input under call "class". Inside this input you give the exact name you have write after "new" in you code (Hammer). Now it should work, you code will be able to find the movirclip in your library.

Comment: 2- you can don't use the library as in my 1st solution and for that you just need to placr your hammer movieclip on the stage, give it an instance name. Then in your code at the place of  var hammer:Hammer... You erase this line and in then you can directly use is like that : nameofinstance.addEventListener it should correct you problem

Comment: By the way I just edit my first answer post, I forgot stage.addChild and to help you in the case you try to link your library with the script, here is an example of movieclip ready to communicate with script I found online http://www.htmlgoodies.com/img/2010/02/step_2.jpg

Comment: Thanks for your answer @XueFang. I following your steps nothing error but why can not mousedown hammer down. This file http://we.tl/Wo42Bt3PK3

Comment: I got your file, I'm seeing what problem you are facing, I correct it, write some comments to help you and send you the result.